# Cordova/Phonegap Input select doesn't work

Tags: android, cordova, uiscrollview, fastclick.js

I have a problem...I have a Cordova/Phonegap app and I want to port this app from cordova 2.0 to cordova 5.1.1...Now when I start the app the select input don't work...I'm using Iscroll.js and fastclick.js...Maybe they are the problem...Is there anyone that fix this problem? In the normal case when I click on select the device open the native select...this is my select:

```
<select type="text" id="myId" style="width: 99%" onchange="function()">
                        <option selected="selected">---</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                        <option>6</option>
                        <option>7</option>
                        <option>8</option>
                        <option>9</option>
                    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code on my iPhone and the select comes up as expected. Try and exclude your javascript libraries to find out which one is interfering with your select.

On a side note, *type="text"* has no effect on the select. It is only applicable on input elements.